# How to get the li in a ul which index is not equal to 2,I know how to get the index gt or lt 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Now I want to make all the `li` hide excep the `li` which index is equal to show.I have write the codes,but can I have a simple code than this? jQuery have `eq,gt,lt`,but not have `not eq` method.

```
 $('#ulMenu').children("li:lt(2)").hide();
 $('#ulMenu').children("li:gt(2)").hide();

 $('#ulMenu').children("li:not(2)").hide(); //wrong method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine eq and not selector:

```
 $('#ulMenu li:not(:eq(2))').hide();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f63eux67/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just use the CSS selectors straight away:

```
$("ul li:not(:nth-child(2))").hide();
```

All `li` which are not the `nth-child(n)` of the `ul`.

Snippet:

```js
$("ul li:not(:nth-child(2))").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li><li>four</li><li>five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
$('#ulMenu li').eq(someIndexHere).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of one big unreadable selector, another method is to hide all and than show the required one:

```
$('#ulMenu li').hide().filter(':eq(2)').show();
```